# In C++, how can a percentage progress bar be placed at the bottom of a Linux terminal while general printouts are displayed (not overwritten) also?

Tags: c++, linux, progress-bar

I have a program that loops over some files, doing various things to them. With each file, the program prints some output to the terminal. This output could be of various forms (over which I have no control).

I want to have a percentage progress bar displayed solely at the bottom of the terminal output, below all of the continuous output of the file processing activities. How could I do this?

Note that I do not have access to ncurses.

Using guidance from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831323/how-should-i-add-a-stationary-progress-bar-to-a-c-program-that-produces-termin), I have a basic attempt here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print_progress_bar(int percentage){
  string progress = "[" + string(percentage, '*') + string(100 - percentage, ' ') + "]";
  cout << progress << "\r\033[F\033[F\033[F" << flush;
}

void print_stuff(){
    int number_of_lines = (rand() % 9) + 1;
    for (int i=0; i <= number_of_lines; ++i){
        cout << "some junk output of " << number_of_lines << " lines\n";
    }
}

int main(){
  cout << endl;
  for (int i=0; i <= 100; ++i){
    std::cout << "processing file number " << i << "\n";
    print_stuff();
    print_progress_bar(i);
    usleep(10000);
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking "how do I move the cursor to a known place in the terminal"?

Comment: Not really. As shown in the code, I know how to do this to some extent. What I find problematic is not overwriting the ongoing terminal output of the file processing while also maintaining a single copy of the progress bar at the end of the terminal. I'm seeking guidance on how to do this.

Comment: So, if you can't use ncurses, I expect you will have to do your own "virtual terminal buffer", and keep track of where your progress bar is in relation to your other output. If you are certain your lines won't exceed the current line, you could possibly use the "scroll up" command in ANSI escape codes, and then erase line and redraw the bottom line.

Comment: Using ncurses would be simpler.  But if OP is determined to use hard-coded escapes, he could set scrolling margins before writing the informational message (to exclude an area at the bottom of the screen for progress bar) and use cursor addressing for moving to/from the progress bar.